# ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function in MySQL Cluster 7.3

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

```
select count(*) from student 
group by branch
```

This query is perfectly working for me,and i got the output like this.

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       32 |
|       27 |
|       50 |
|       52 |
|       58 |
|       57 |
|       59 |
+----------+
```

7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
But when i use

```
select max(count(*)) from student group by branch;
```

It result an error

> ERROR 1111 : Invalid use of group function

Please help me.

I am using MySQL Cluster 7.3

Comment: The error occurs where there is a faulty assumption of the wrapping layers of queries with dangling `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` in outer (later) lines of a query

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest aggregate functions. You need to use a subquery.

```
SELECT MAX(c) 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
      FROM student
      GROUP BY branch) AS t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the following

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM student GROUP BY branch ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1`

**OR**

use your current query as a subquery

`SELECT MAX(t.total) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM student GROUP BY branch) AS t`